# Wait only one element to load in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

Is there a way that I only need to wait one element to load in a site and them go to another one using selenium?

I'm crawling a site that takes too long to load everything, but the info that I need is only a text that is the first thing that load.

I'm trying something like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv") 
wait =  WebDriverWait(driver, 1)

for site in df.site: 
    driver.get(site)

    search = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@itemprop="recipeInstructions"]//span[@tabindex="0"]')))
    search = "".join(list(map(lambda x: x.text+"---",search)))

    if(search):
        driver.execute_script("window.stop();")

    print(search)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for visibility of that specific element only.
So, in case `//div[@itemprop="recipeInstructions"]//span[@tabindex="0"]` is **unique** locator of that specific element you can use code like this:

```py
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

for site in df.site: 
    driver.get(site)
    text_you_want_to_get_is = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@itemprop="recipeInstructions"]//span[@tabindex="0"]'))).text
```